# semaphore initialization in c

Tags: c, semaphore

```
arg.val = 1;

    if (sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT) == -1 ){
            perror("Creating semaphore failed");
            exit(1);
    }
    else {
            printf("Creating a semaphore with ID: %d \n",sem_id);
            if (semctl(sem_id, 0, SETVAL, arg) == -1 ) {                       
                    perror("Initialization of semaphore failed\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
    }
```

I am trying to create and initialize a semaphore and when I am compiling my program it returns me:
"Initialization of semaphore failed
:Identifier removed

Could you explain me the reason why this happens??

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket on your if statement.

Comment: i just forgot it!sorry!can you notice something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT) == -1 )
```

is parsed (because `==` binds stronger than `=`)

```
if (sem_id = (semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT) == -1) )
```

you probably want

```
if ((sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation == has a higher precedence than the operation =. I believe this means this means that sem_id is getting set to a true value. You should group the operation in the if statement.

```
if((sem_id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1){
```